# Finetune model with different number of classes using object detection API

Tags: object-detection-api, transfer-learning, mobilenet, tensorflow-model-garden

### Scope

I'm trying to transfer learn a SSD MobileNet v3 (small) model using the object detection API, but my dataset has only 8 classes, while the provided model is pre-trained on COCO (90 classes). If I leave the number of classes of the model intact, I can train with no problem.

### Problem

Changing the pipeline.config *num_classes* yields an assignment error because the layers shape doesn't match with checkpoint variables:

```
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: 2 root error(s) found.
    (0) Invalid argument: Assign requires shapes of both tensors to match. lhs shape= [1,1,288,27] rhs shape= [1,1,288,273]
        [[{{node save/Assign_15}}]]
    (1) Invalid argument: Assign requires shapes of both tensors to match. lhs shape= [1,1,288,27] rhs shape= [1,1,288,273]
        [[{{node save/Assign_15}}]]
        [[save/RestoreV2/_404]]
```

### Questions

- Is there any way to change the number of classes and still do transfer learning (like loading only the variables with matching size)? Or do I have to cope between training from scratch with only 8 classes or fine tuning with 90 classes?
- Is there any tool to manually "trim" the pre trained checkpoint variables?

---

Dataset: [ITD Dataset](https://github.com/tools-dataset/Industrial-Tools-Detection-Dataset)

Model: [SSD MobileNetV3 - small](http://download.tensorflow.org/models/object_detection/ssd_mobilenet_v3_small_coco_2020_01_14.tar.gz) (from the [Model Zoo](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/g3doc/tf1_detection_zoo.md))

pipeline.config:

```proto
# SSDLite with Mobilenet v3 small feature extractor.
# Trained on COCO14, initialized from scratch.
# TPU-compatible.
# Users should configure the fine_tune_checkpoint field in the train config as
# well as the label_map_path and input_path fields in the train_input_reader and
# eval_input_reader. Search for "PATH_TO_BE_CONFIGURED" to find the fields that
# should be configured.

model {
  ssd {
    inplace_batchnorm_update: true
    freeze_batchnorm: false
    num_classes: 8
    box_coder {
      faster_rcnn_box_coder {
        y_scale: 10.0
        x_scale: 10.0
        height_scale: 5.0
        width_scale: 5.0
      }
    }
    matcher {
      argmax_matcher {
        matched_threshold: 0.5
        unmatched_threshold: 0.5
        ignore_thresholds: false
        negatives_lower_than_unmatched: true
        force_match_for_each_row: true
        use_matmul_gather: true
      }
    }
    similarity_calculator {
      iou_similarity {
      }
    }
    encode_background_as_zeros: true
    anchor_generator {
      ssd_anchor_generator {
        num_layers: 6
        min_scale: 0.2
        max_scale: 0.95
        aspect_ratios: 1.0
        aspect_ratios: 2.0
        aspect_ratios: 0.5
        aspect_ratios: 3.0
        aspect_ratios: 0.3333
      }
    }
    image_resizer {
      fixed_shape_resizer {
        height: 320
        width: 320
      }
    }
    box_predictor {
      convolutional_box_predictor {
        min_depth: 0
        max_depth: 0
        num_layers_before_predictor: 0
        use_dropout: false
        dropout_keep_probability: 0.8
        kernel_size: 3
        use_depthwise: true
        box_code_size: 4
        apply_sigmoid_to_scores: false
        class_prediction_bias_init: -4.6
        conv_hyperparams {
          activation: RELU_6,
          regularizer {
            l2_regularizer {
              weight: 0.00004
            }
          }
          initializer {
            random_normal_initializer {
              stddev: 0.03
              mean: 0.0
            }
          }
          batch_norm {
            train: true,
            scale: true,
            center: true,
            decay: 0.97,
            epsilon: 0.001,
          }
        }
      }
    }
    feature_extractor {
      type: 'ssd_mobilenet_v3_small'
      min_depth: 16
      depth_multiplier: 1.0
      use_depthwise: true
      conv_hyperparams {
        activation: RELU_6,
        regularizer {
          l2_regularizer {
            weight: 0.00004
          }
        }
        initializer {
          truncated_normal_initializer {
            stddev: 0.03
            mean: 0.0
          }
        }
        batch_norm {
          train: true,
          scale: true,
          center: true,
          decay: 0.97,
          epsilon: 0.001,
        }
      }
      override_base_feature_extractor_hyperparams: true
    }
    loss {
      classification_loss {
        weighted_sigmoid_focal {
          alpha: 0.75,
          gamma: 2.0
        }
      }
      localization_loss {
        weighted_smooth_l1 {
          delta: 1.0
        }
      }
      classification_weight: 1.0
      localization_weight: 1.0
    }
    normalize_loss_by_num_matches: true
    normalize_loc_loss_by_codesize: true
    post_processing {
      batch_non_max_suppression {
        score_threshold: 1e-8
        iou_threshold: 0.6
        max_detections_per_class: 100
        max_total_detections: 100
        use_static_shapes: true
      }
      score_converter: SIGMOID
    }
  }
}

train_config: {
  batch_size: 16 #512
  sync_replicas: true
  startup_delay_steps: 0
  replicas_to_aggregate: 32
  num_steps: 0
  data_augmentation_options {
    ssd_random_crop_pad_fixed_aspect_ratio {
    }
  }  
  data_augmentation_options {
    random_horizontal_flip {
    }
  }
  optimizer {
    momentum_optimizer: {
      learning_rate: {
        cosine_decay_learning_rate {
          learning_rate_base: 0.4
          total_steps: 800000
          warmup_learning_rate: 0.13333
          warmup_steps: 2000
        }
      }
      momentum_optimizer_value: 0.9
    }
    use_moving_average: false
  }
  fine_tune_checkpoint: "./model/model.ckpt"
  fine_tune_checkpoint_type: "detection"
  fine_tune_checkpoint_version: V1
  keep_checkpoint_every_n_hours: 2.0
  max_number_of_boxes: 100
  unpad_groundtruth_tensors: false
}

train_input_reader: {
  tf_record_input_reader {
    input_path: "./data/train.record"
  }
  label_map_path: "./annotations/label_map.pbtxt"
  shuffle: true
}

eval_config: {
  num_examples: 1296
}

eval_input_reader: {
  tf_record_input_reader {
    input_path: "./data/val.record"
  }
  label_map_path: "./annotations/label_map.pbtxt"
  shuffle: true
  num_readers: 1
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is mainly the idea of the Tensorflow object detection garden to fine-tune the models! You should change :

```
fine_tune_checkpoint_type = "detection"
```

to :

```
fine_tune_checkpoint_type = "fine_tune"
```

and then when you call the object_detection/model_main*.py, you should be careful that the model_dir you are passing as argument is empty. In that way the script will be able to load the fine_tune_checkpoint you pointed at in the config with the 90 classes, and it will create a new checkpoint in your empty model directory with the saved weights and your 8 classes. After that you will even be able to load previous your previous custom checkpoint in case your training as stopped.

EDIT : reference for the fine-tune input check this answer : https://github.com/tensorflow/models/issues/8892#issuecomment-680207038

Comment: Funny, I thought only "detection" and "classification" were the only valid inputs. I haven't seen the "fine_tune" option anywhere in the documentation. I'll be trying it anyway, with 'load_all_detection_checkpoint_vars: true' but how do I know that the variables were loaded? I've already tried changing the modeldir path, but I couldn't tell if the checkpoint was loaded.

Comment: Just did your suggestion, and it worked! Looks like it works even with the 'detection' option. Changing the 'modeldir' path really helped though, and I could train from where I had stopped before. Thanks again!

Comment: I was going to say I have no clue to see if the checkpoints are correctly loaded but to compare the loss with and without which isn't really precise ;) but glad it helped! I think it was the modeldir then. Good luck!

Comment: I could tell now because I received warning that the loaded variables didn't match the shape of the model, so I guess it really loaded everything it needed.